# ObjectDisposedException when outputting to console

Tags: c#, exception, console, dispose

If I have the following code, I have no runtime or compilation problems:

```
if (ConsoleAppBase.NORMAL_EXIT_CODE == code)
{
    StdOut.WriteLine(msg);
}
else
{
    StdErr.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

However, in trying to make this more concise, I switched to the following code:

```
(ConsoleAppBase.NORMAL_EXIT_CODE == code
    ? StdOut
    : StdErr
).WriteLine(msg);
```

When I have this code, I get the following exception at runtime:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter

Can you explain why this happens?  Can I avoid it and have more concise code like I wanted?

**Edit:** whoops, sorry, I forgot to note where these mysterious `StdOut` and `StdErr` come from:

```
/// <summary>
/// Define these so that they can be accessible to unit tests so that
/// a different TextWriter instance can be used for capturing output
/// for verification.
/// </summary>
internal static TextWriter StdOut = Console.Out;
internal static TextWriter StdErr = Console.Error;
```

**Update:** hm, I just got the same exception with the original, lengthy code, so apparently something else is awry.  I'll check what my test cases are doing.

**Update again:**  turns out in my tests I was rerouting standard out but not standard error, but then I did try to write to standard error and it wigged out.  My fix:

```
var standardOut = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput())
                      {
                          AutoFlush = true
                      };
Console.SetOut(standardOut);

// Added this:
var standardError = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardError())
                        {
                            AutoFlush = true
                        };
Console.SetError(standardError);
```

I'm marking [ChaosPandion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907714/objectdisposedexception-when-outputting-to-console/2907756#2907756) as the correct one since he correctly identified my test as being screwy.

Comment: Did you look at the IL? Maybe its because of some compiler optimization? Do this happen in release, debug or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation is that the circumstances of your test are different. For instance, in test one you are writing `StdOut` but in test two you are writing to `StdErr` because of some sort of error. Open up the debugger and make sure you aren't disposing of either before executing this code.

Comment: This might be on the right track.  In some tests, it branched to `StdOut`, and in others, including the one on which it failed, it branched to `StdErr`.  Maybe I should have some kind of test cleanup method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method you're looking for is:

```
Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

And

```
Console.Error.WriteLine(msg);
```

**Edit:**

I believe to use `Console.Out` and `Console.Error` you may have to set them with the `SetError` and `SetOut` methods actually.

Instead you can try to call these functions:

```
Console.OpenStandardError();
Console.OpenStandardOutput();
```

Which means you may have to make your own writers, and manage closing the stream since these return `System.IO.Stream` objects.

So:

```
TextWriter StdOut = new TextWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
TextWriter StdErr = new TextWriter(Console.OpenStandardError());
```

I just use the `Console.Write` / `Console.WriteLine` in my coding. Also `Debug.Write` and `Debug.WriteLine` for the Error Stream.

Comment: Sorry, good call, I updated my question to show that my `StdOut` and `StdErr` come from `Console.Out` and `Console.Error`.